# Add to ~/.zshrc file with python

Tags: python, shell, file, path, zsh

I'm trying to write a cli that will take a users path that they input into the command line, then add this path to the correct path file depending on their shell - in this case zsh. I have tried using:

```
    shell = str(subprocess.check_output("echo $SHELL", shell=True))
    click.echo("Enter the path you would like to add:")
    path = input()
    if 'zsh' in shell:
        with open(".zshrc", 'w') as zsh:
            zsh.write(f'export PATH="$PATH:{path}"')
```

This throws no errors but doesn't seem to add to the actual ~./zshrc file.
Is there a better way to append to the file without manually opening the file and typing it in?

New to this so sorry if it's a stupid question...

Comment: It might be worth noting that I am only building this for macs

Comment: You don't need a subprocess to check the value of an environment variable. `shell = os.enviroin['SHELL']`.

Comment: @James : Did you ensure that you were running this program from your home-directory?

Comment: @James: Even if your program worked, it would be quite dangerous, because you open `.zshrc` for writing, which means that any present content of this file would be lost.

Comment: @user1934428 thanks for the advice. I have followed chepner 's advice to switch to .zprofile and use append rather than write.

Comment: @James: Are you aware that `.zprofile` is sourced only if Zsh is run as a login shell? This might be good enough for your concrete case, but at least you should know it, to avoid surprises.

Comment: Yes thank you when the program is run I check for the shell and then append to the correct login file depending on the login shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the file in *append* mode. Your code also assumes that the current working directory is the user's home directory, which is not a good assumption to make.

```
from pathlib import Path
import os


if 'zsh' in os.environ.get("SHELL", ""):
    with open(Path.home() / ".zshrc", 'a') as f:
        f.write(f'export PATH={path}:$PATH')
```

`with (Path.home() / ".zshrc').open("a") as f:` would work as well.

Note that `.zprofile` would be the preferred location for updating an envirornent variable like `PATH`, rather than `.zshrc`.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly. (would upvote but don't have enough reputation)

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Just want to put the answer here if anyone comes across the same problem.
Instead of trying to open the file with

```
with open(".zshrc", 'w') as zsh:
    zsh.write(f'export PATH="$PATH:{path}"')
```

you can just do

```
subprocess.call(f"echo 'export PATH=$PATH:{path}' >> ~/.zshrc", shell=True)
```

If anybody has a way of removing from ~/.zshrc with python that would be very helpful...